# Выдает ошибку "single positional indexer is out-of-bounds" при при проверке однородных данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть датафрейм:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Id':[14038.0, 15053.0, 4765.0, 10783.0, 12915.0,5809.0, 11993.0, 5172.0, 10953.0, 11935.0,7917.0],
        'Square':[48.0, 65.7, 44.9, 39.6, 80.4,53.4, 80.3, 64.5, 53.8, 64.7, 212.9],
        'LifeSquare':[29.4, 40.0, 29.2, 23.8, 46.7,52.7,0 ,0 , 52.4, 0, 211.2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Задача - Скорректировать параметр LifeSquare перед обучением модели.
Написал функцию для отбора ближайших подобных чисел:

```
def square_correction(data):
    item = 'LifeSquare'
    valid = data.loc[~((data[item] > data['Square'] * 0.8) |\
                       (data[item] < data['Square'] * 0.3)|\
                       (data[item]).isna())]
    invalid = data.loc[(data[item] > data['Square'] * 0.8) |\
                       (data[item] < data['Square'] * 0.3)|\
                       (data[item]).isna()]

    best_feature, item_by_best_feature = best_params(valid, item)

    for i in range(0, len(invalid[item])):
        flat_id = invalid[item].index[i]
        best_feature_meaning = invalid[best_feature][flat_id]


        bigger = valid.loc[(valid[best_feature] >= best_feature_meaning)].reset_index().iloc[0]
        smoller = valid.loc[(valid[best_feature] <= best_feature_meaning)].reset_index().iloc[-1]

        difference_up  = (bigger[best_feature] - data[best_feature][flat_id])
        difference_down = (data[best_feature][flat_id] - smoller[best_feature])

        text = f'flat id:{flat_id}. {item} was changed. {i+1} of {len(invalid[item])} done.'
        if  difference_up ==  difference_down:
            print(text)
            data[item][flat_id] = item_by_best_feature[best_feature_meaning]
        elif not difference_up >=  difference_down:
            print(text)
            data[item][flat_id] = bigger[item]
        else:
            print(text)
            data[item][flat_id] = smoller[item]    


    print(f'best feature: {best_feature}. {len(invalid)} rows was changed.')
    return data
```

запускаем функцию:

```
df = square_correction(df)
```

Всё идёт нормально до последней строчки, где jupyter notebook выдает ошибку:

```
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Почему ему одно наблюдение из всех так не нравится?

P.S. На учебном датафрейме (10000 наблюдений) выдаёт ту же ошибку:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-d4ceb1216100> in <module>
----> 1 data = square_correction(data)

<ipython-input-16-c8f2bf3d18d3> in square_correction(data)
     20 
     21 
---> 22         bigger = valid.loc[(valid[best_feature] >= best_feature_meaning)].reset_index().iloc[0]
     23         smoller = valid.loc[(valid[best_feature] <= best_feature_meaning)].reset_index().iloc[-1]
     24 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1498 
   1499             maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
-> 1500             return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
   1501 
   1502     def _is_scalar_access(self, key):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   2228 
   2229             # validate the location
-> 2230             self._validate_integer(key, axis)
   2231 
   2232             return self._get_loc(key, axis=axis)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_integer(self, key, axis)
   2137         len_axis = len(self.obj._get_axis(axis))
   2138         if key >= len_axis or key < -len_axis:
-> 2139             raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
   2140 
   2141     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup):

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже у вас бывают случаи когда `valid.loc[(valid[best_feature] >= best_feature_meaning)]` возвращает пустой DataFrame, у которого вообще нет строк и, соответственно, `valid.loc[(valid[best_feature] >= best_feature_meaning)].reset_index().iloc[0]` выдает ошибку.

Воспроизведение ошибки:

```
In [276]: pd.DataFrame().iloc[0]
...
skipped
...
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Comment: Когда раскладываю строчку кода на данных, выдающих ошибку, данные есть. Ошибка появляется при сравнении

Comment: @Vadim.M., данная ошибка может возникнуть только в том случае если DF пустой. Следовательно valid.loc[...] возвращает пустой DF

Answer (score 0):

Вылечено костылём из if:

```
    for i in range(0, len(invalid[item])):
        flat_id = invalid[item].index[i]
        flat = invalid.loc[(invalid['Id'] == flat_id)]

        if not flat['HouseYear'].empty:

        # для обхода ошибки при сравнении типа данных использован не по назначению метод .mean()
            if any(valid.loc[(valid['HouseYear'] == flat['HouseYear'].mean())][item]):
                df = valid.loc[(valid['HouseYear'] == flat['HouseYear'].mean())]
                tmp_KSq = df[item].mean()

                if any(valid.loc[(valid['Rooms'] == flat['Rooms'].mean())][item]):
                    df = valid.loc[(valid['Rooms'] == flat['Rooms'].mean())]
                    tmp_KSq = df[item].mean()
```